# Which IP should be whitelisted when using Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am hosting an web app at azure. 
My problem is, that my MySQL Database, that is not hosted at Microsoft Azure, requires an IP to be whitelisted. Otherwise I am not able to connect from the server to the DB.

Do you know which IPs should be whitelisted? 
I have come across the IPs that are under Properties -> Outbound IP Adresses, fe.
[image: https://i.imgur.com/S7Fdqae.png]

Are the IPs that are inside that Block the adresses that try to access my database, should they be whitelisted? Can they change?

Comment: You answered your own question: You have to whitelist all of those outbound IP addresses, since those are where your web app traffic will come from.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for your answer! I already thought that it would be those adresses, BUT- can they change?

Comment: It's possible that the range changes.

Comment: I have found the website that gives me the ranges for the IPs, you can find it under https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found out that these IP Adresses are the outbound adresses- YES, they can change. You can find out the IPs under https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653

Microsoft gives an IP range to every server farm (depending on your server location, eg. Europe, America...) - Your server IP can change within that IP range- when you want to whitelist your Server, you have to whitelist that range.